# Objective C - Two synthesized properties using the same Instance Variable?

Tags: objective-c, ios, properties, key-value-coding, foundation

I have a class that represents some data.
I'm getting this data from a Web Service in the JSON format.
The web service does not conform to the Objective - C naming convention. More specifically, all the attributes of an object starts with capital letter, for example `Name`.

I want to be able to utilize the built-in KVC but still build my objects with the Objective-C naming convention.

So in my public class declaration I'm declaring one property:

```
@interface TVPage : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
@end
```

And In my *.m file I'm declaring a category extension to conform to the Web Service naming convention:

```
@interface TVPage ()
@property (nonatomic, copy , getter = name , setter = setName:) NSString *Name;
@end
```

In the private property I'm specifying the getter and setter that I want to actually access the data.

All I want to achieve is just another method, called `Name` that will actually call `name` behind the scene. (`setName:` actually fits for both `Name` and `name`)

My question is, when I'm synthesizing the properties like that:

```
@implementation TVPage
@synthesize name;
@synthesize Name;
@end
```

Will it generate two different Instance Variables called `Name` and `name` or is it smart enough to understand not to do that and create only one named `name`?

Can I tell the compiler explicitly - "Do not generate IVar for this property"?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

### Why would I want to do that?

A lot of you asked me what exactly am I trying to achieve here.
Well, what I'm trying to do is to make my life easier when it comes to parsing the data returned from the web service.

The data is returned as a JSON String. That means that when I'll parse it, I'll probably get back NSDictionaries to represent the data.

I want to easily create objects that I designed to hold this data, because it's not convenient, safe or readable to work with dictionaries as a data model.

Now, the Key-Value Coding features allow me to set the attributes of an object, directly from a dictionary using `setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:`

But this will work only if my object actually have accessor methods with the same names as the dictionary's keys. If there is a key that don't have a matching attribute in my object, I'll get an exception from `setValue:forUndefinedKey:`.

To avoid that I want to create [Facade Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) that will conform to the Key-Value Coding methods implied by the attribute names from the server. At the same time I want that the implementation of that interface will access the same data that the "regular" interface access.

Comment: Did you try it or should we try it for you?

Comment: But how could I tell? In any case only one of them is going to actually being used. The question is not if it is reliable (because it is) but rather if it is going to allocate useless memory in every instance of this class.

Comment: What is the purpose of the capital letter Name property?

Comment: I'm editing my question to provide more details...

Comment: you could try that with a very very simple test: `object.name = @"a"; object.Name = @"b"; NSLog(@"a:%@, b:%@", object.name, object.Name);`

Comment: @Ahti That's actually wrong. I know that the object.Name is actually calling object.name. What I don't know is if there is a "Name" ivar in addition to "name" ivar. And as it appears there is...

Comment: God help everybody who will mantain such a code!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said, write some test code and then don't continue with whatever you are doing.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, copy , getter = name , setter = setName:) NSString *Name;
```

and `@synthesize` both. To see what happens we put some logging code into our s/getter, like this.

```
- (void)setName:(NSString *)aName {
    NSLog(@"setter called");
    name = aName;
}

- (NSString *)name {
    NSLog(@"getter called");
    return name;
}
```

and now have some testing fun.

```
NSLog(@"setValue:forKey: with Key name");
[self setValue:@"Name" forKey:@"name"];
NSLog(@"setValue:forKey: with Key Name");
[self setValue:@"Name" forKey:@"Name"];

NSLog(@"valueForKey: with Key name");
NSLog(@"ptr: %p", [self valueForKey:@"name"]);
NSLog(@"valueForKey: with Key Name");
NSLog(@"ptr: %p", [self valueForKey:@"Name"]);

NSLog(@"\n");

NSLog(@"calling setter via dot-notation for name");
self.name = @"foo";
NSLog(@"calling setter via dot-notation for Name");
self.Name = @"foo";

NSLog(@"calling getter via dot-notation for name");
NSLog(@"ptr: %p", self.name);
NSLog(@"calling getter via dot-notation for Name");
NSLog(@"ptr: %p", self.Name);
```

let's run it. et voila.

```
[4115:f803] setValue:forKey: with Key name
[4115:f803] setter called
[4115:f803] setValue:forKey: with Key Name
[4115:f803] setter called
[4115:f803] valueForKey: with Key name
[4115:f803] getter called
[4115:f803] ptr: 0x36d8
[4115:f803] valueForKey: with Key Name          <-----
[4115:f803] ptr: 0x0                            <-----
[4115:f803] 
[4115:f803] calling setter via dot-notation for name
[4115:f803] setter called
[4115:f803] calling setter via dot-notation for Name
[4115:f803] setter called
[4115:f803] calling getter via dot-notation for name
[4115:f803] getter called
[4115:f803] ptr: 0x3758
[4115:f803] calling getter via dot-notation for Name
[4115:f803] getter called
[4115:f803] ptr: 0x3758
```

You see? The custom getter `name` is not called for `valueForKey:@"Name"`. However the custom setter is called. But probably only because you can't capitalize a capital letter.

I hope you don't just blindly use `setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:` with a bunch of values. You have to validate those keys anyway, because you don't want to call that method for keys like `self`, `description` and so on. So while you validate the keys just "decapitalize" the names of the keys.
Removing the capital letter is IMHO a much cleaner way because it doesn't fail for half of the accessor methods like it happened with those strange shadow variables.

Comment: Alright, Alright... Code readability is more important to me than efficiency. Thank you for you efforts.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can tell the compiler. You need to not use `@synthesize` but `@dynamic` which just tells the compiler to trust you that there is an implementation of that somewhere, and don't throw warnings etc.

Comment: Would this still create the setters / getters?

Comment: as is said, it tells the compiler "the getter and setter for this do exist, you don't need to worry", so no, the compiler would not generate setter and getter. in your case, you'd want to use `@synthesize` for name and `@dynamic` for Name.

Comment: Ok.  It looks like he still wants to be able to use `-Name` though so when using `@dynamic` he'd still have to write the getter manually, correct?

Comment: @Tim no, because of the `getter = name , setter = setName:` when declaring the property. that makes all accesses to that property use the getters and setters specified

Comment: @Ahti - Matthias was right, I can't assure that the right getter will be called, so I'm abandoning the idea. Sory, but thank you for your effort.

Comment: Actually now I tried it with "@dynamic" - and it's not even giving me the wrong result - it just crashes with "setValue:forUndefinedKey:" so "@dynamic" is not the solution anyway...